# C# Multiple String Comparision with Same Value

Tags: c#, string

Please have a look at the below case, surely that will be interesting..

if i want to assign same value to multiple objects i will use something like this

```
string1 = string2 = string3 = string 4 = "some string";
```

Now what i want to do is, i want to compare string1, string2, string3 and string4 with "someotherstring"... questions is is there any way to do this without writing individual comparision. *i.e.*

```
string1 == "someotherstring" || string2 == "someotherstring" || string3 == "someotherstring" || string4 == "someotherstring"
```

Hope i was able to explain the question.. kindly provide me help on this.

Regards,
Paresh Rathod

Comment: How would you want to write it ?

Answer (score 15):

In C# 3.0, you can write a very trivial extension method:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static bool In(this string @this, params string[] strings)
    {
        return strings.Contains(@this); 
    }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
if ("some string".In(string1, string2, string3, string4))
{
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 8):

For your case you can try something like this

```
if (new string[] { string1, string2, string3, string4 }.Contains("someotherstring"))
{
}
```

Comment: and for an "and" operation: strings.All(x => x=="someotherstring")

Comment: Minor detail: in C# 3.0 you can shorten the syntax a little bit more by omitting the type of the array (it will be inferred). i.e. : `if( new []{s1,s2,s3,s4}.Contains("s"))`

Comment: this gives compilation errr "cannot access private method 'Contains' here"

Answer (score 5):

I find LINQ very expressive, and would consider using it for this problem:

```
new[] { string1, string2, string3, string4 }.Any(s => s == "some string")
```

Answer (score 3):

No there isn't in C# but you could write it this way:

```
 (string1 == string2 && string2 == string3 && 
  string3 == string4 && string4 == "someotherstring")
```

Comment: Hi James..
Thanks for your reply..
If you will take a look again at my question.. i have used ||. Means, any of string1, string2, string3 and string4 should be equal to "someotherstring"...

I think that.. your case will be applicable if i want to check, whether all 4 string instances are equal to "someotherstring" or not?
Am i right?

Regards,
Paresh Rathod
KlixMedia

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function that simplifies reading the code :

```
compareToFirst( "someotherthing", string1, string2, string3, string4);
```

If you want to compare this list of strings to successive "other strings", you may want to create a list object "myStringList" in which you'd add string1/2/3/4 then define a function to be able to write

```
compare( "someotherthing", myStringList );
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe so. How would you know which one did not compare or did match. There would be no way to evaluate the side-effect of such a comparison.