# Is there any compare operator in c# like SQL's IN statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql

This is not a specific question but a generic question which was in my mind from long time

I have to check one variable if it contains a value from a list of strings

for e.g.

```
status == "Open" || status =="Active" || status =="Reopen" || status = "InActive" etc..
```

In SQL it is very easy to write this kind of statements e.g.

select * from ticket where status in ("Open","Active","Reopen","InActive)

I wonder we don't have such easy statement in C#?

Do anybody know any easy way like SQL to write this kind of statements without using generic types of if else ,foreach loop or LINQ etc..

I know LINQ is there but still it is not as simple as IN of sql

Comment: Doesn't `&&` stand for `AND` (and not for `OR`)?

Comment: I think the answer you are looking for is the top answer in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962791/c-sharp-multiple-string-comparision-with-same-value 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962791/c-sharp-multiple-string-comparision-with-same-value

Comment: sorry for the type mistake , i modified my question

Comment: @DanielCasserly , thanks for the link, I searched but not found it before posting this question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
tickets.Where(t => new[] {"Open",
                          "Active",
                          "Reopen",
                          "InActive"}.Any(x => x == t.status))
```

You can also use the Contain method instead of the Any method, but use the Any method if there's any comparement logic you would like to implement, instead of the default equality comparer.

OR

Implement extensions to support IN method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool In<TItem>(this TItem source, Func<TItem, TItem, bool> comparer, IEnumerable<TItem> items)
    {
        return items.Any(item => comparer(source, item));
    }

    public static bool In<TItem, T>(this TItem source, Func<TItem, T> selector, IEnumerable<TItem> items)
    {
        return items.Select(selector).Contains(selector(source));
    }

    public static bool In<T>(this T source, IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        return items.Contains(source);
    }

    public static bool In<TItem>(this TItem source, Func<TItem, TItem, bool> comparer, params TItem[] items)
    {
        return source.In(comparer, (IEnumerable<TItem>)items);
    }

    public static bool In<TItem, T>(this TItem source, Func<TItem, T> selector, params TItem[] items)
    {
        return source.In(selector, (IEnumerable<TItem>)items);
    }

    public static bool In<T>(this T source, params T[] items)
    {
        return source.In((IEnumerable<T>)items);
    }
}
```

And use like this:

```
bool b;

b = 7.In(3, 5, 6, 7, 8); // true
b = "hi".In("", "10", "hi", "Hello"); // true
b = "hi".In("", "10", "Hi", "Hello"); // false
b = "hi".In((s1, s2) => string.Equals(s1, s2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase), "", "10", "Hi"); // true

var tuples = new List<Tuple<int, string>>();

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    tuples.Add(Tuple.Create(i, ""));
}

var tuple = Tuple.Create(3, "");

b = tuple.In(tup => tup.Item1, tuples); // true
```

Comment: For long lists it would be faster to use a HashSet than an array. Also care should be taken to ensure the HashSet is only created once and not once for each iteration of the loop. A static readonly property can be good for this.

With arrays, Contains() does a linier search for each item looked up, for HashSets it uses an index on the hash. But for short lists like this the array may be faster because calculating hashes takes time.

Answer (score 9):

```
(new [] { "Open", "Active", "Reopen", "InActive" }).Contains(status)
```

Comment: The parentheses are not necessary.

Comment: this gives compilation errr "cannot access private method 'Contains' here"

Comment: @ImranRizvi add `using System.Linq;` at beginning of your code file

Comment: @ImranRizvi, all Linq methods are extension methods. They declared separated from types that they extend. Тo enable extensions for a particular type, you need add namespace to make compiler detect exact location.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.

```
(new List<string>{ "Open", "Active", "Reopen", "InActive" }).Contains("status");
```

I also like the c# 3.0 feature of creating extension to String class

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static bool In(this string @this, params string[] strings)
    {
        return strings.Contains(@this); 
    }
}
```

and later we can use it in Simplest way

```
status.Contains("Open", "Active", "Reopen", "InActive");
```

This is great if you have to write many statements like this I prefer to write this extension for if I am writing old style for atleast 5-10 statement statement in 2 or more files.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to create an extension method that can handle this as mentioned earlier...

Add the necessary imports

```
using System;
using System.Linq; // required if using .Contains() or .Any()
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

Create an Extension class. The following gives three options for the extension method.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    
    public static bool InV1(this string input, string[] collection)
    {       
        if (collection == null || collection.Length == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Parameters empty");
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < collection.Length; i++) 
        {
            if (input.Equals(collection[i]))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        
        return false;
    }
    
    public static bool InV2(this string input, string[] collection)
    {   
        if (collection == null || collection.Length == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Parameters empty");
        }

        if (collection.Contains(input))
        {
            return true;
        }
        
        return false;
    }
    
    // Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3165188/1165173
    public static bool InV3<T>(this T input, params T[] items)
    {   
        if (input == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Input is empty");
        }
        
        if (items == null || items.Length == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Parameters empty");
        }
        
        return items.Any(i => i.Equals(input)); // Any() function exists immediately on first item
    }
}
```

Invoke the extension method within your business logic.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var input = "test1";
        
        var collection = new [] { "test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5" };
        
        // using contains
        var result1 = input.InV1(collection);
        
        Console.WriteLine(result1);
        
        // using iteration
        var result2 = input.InV2(collection);
        
        Console.WriteLine(result2);
        
        // using linq
        var result3 = input.InV3("test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5");

        Console.WriteLine(result3);
        
        // recursively
        var salesIds = new List<int>() { 1230, 1231, 1232, 1233, 1234, 1235, 1236, 1237, 1238, 1239 };
        
        foreach (var id in salesIds)
        {
            if (id.InV3(1230, 1238, 1239))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("exists: " + id);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE: .NET 9 preview makes this even easier, you can use the following...

```
using System;
using System.Buffers;
                    
public class Program
{
    // Credit: Nick Chapsas - 25/03/2024
    // https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q0VENoIXWso
    public static void Main()
    {
        SearchValues<string> searchValues = SearchValues.Create(["Test A", "Test B"], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        Console.WriteLine(searchValues.Contains("Test B"));
        // or another way
        Console.WriteLine(MemoryExtensions.ContainsAny("Test A", searchValues));
    }
}
```